# RoutingExpressionBuilder Dynamic Parameters

Tags: asp.net, routes

Using routing in web forms in ASP.NET 4.0. Looking to use dynamic parameters in the RoutingExpressionBuilder class  something like:

NavigateUrl="<%$ RouteUrl:searchterm={dynamicParameterFromObject} %>">

Would like to know the proper syntax is available.

cheers

Answer (score 0):

Hard to do with the <%$ syntax.

This alternative should work.

```
<%
    String routeName= "<<routeName>>";
    String controllerName= "<<controllerName>>";
    String actionName="<<action>>";

    String url=GetRouteUrl(routeName, new { Controller = controllerName, Action=actionName });
%>

...
NavigateUrl="<%=url%>"
```